# Unique values of expressions using given number of 2's

Tags: algorithm, combinations, dynamic-programming

Given number of 2's how many unique values can be formed by building an expressions out of at most the given number of 2's involving addition or multiplication.

For example, if n = 2, we can form 2 different values:

```
2 + 2 = 4
2 * 2 = 4
2     = 2
```

For n = 3, we can form 4 different values (2, 4, 6 and 8):

```
2 * 2 * 2 = 8
2 * 2 + 2 = 6
2 + 2 * 2 = 6
2 + 2 + 2 = 6
2 * 2     = 4
2 + 2     = 4
2         = 2
```

I want to know for any n, the number of different possible values.

I tried all possible combinations and adding them to hash map, but as n increases the comibnations increase exponentially so brute force won't work. I need another way of calculating or a generalized mathematical formula.

Can it be solved using Dynamic Programming, because I see many sub problems which are used repeatedly.

Comment: You ask "how many unique expressions can be formed" but the examples in your second and third paragraph seem to be counting unique values -- which is it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what programming contest problem is this question trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers so far assume that we want to count the number of distinct *expressions*. This answer assumes that we are looking for the number of different *values* these expressions can evaluate to.

Let's say you have an expression of size at most *n*. Then we can rewrite it as *2<sup>e[1]</sup> + 2<sup>e[2]</sup> + ... + 2<sup>e[m]</sup>* with *e[i] >= 1* and *e[1] + e[2] + ... + e[m] <= n*.

Let's assume *e[1] <= e[2] <= ... <= e[m]*. If *e[i] = e[i+1]* for some *i*, then we can replace the two equal exponents by the single exponent *e[i] + 1*, since *2<sup>e[i]</sup> + 2<sup>e[i+1]</sup> = 2 * 2<sup>e[i]</sup> = 2<sup>e[i] + 1</sup>*. Since *e[i] + 1 <= e[i] + e[i+1]*, the new sequence results in the same value, and still fulfills the condition that the sum of all exponents is smaller than or equal to *n*.

So we only need to count the number of different sequences of exponents *0 < e[1] < e[2] < ... < e[m]*. It is clear that every one of those represents a different value, because the binary representation of a number is unique (and the distinct exponents represent exactly a binary representation).

We can use dynamic programming to count these sequences, for example by picking the exponents from highest to lowest.

Let's define *f(n,hi)* as the number of different ways to choose distinct exponents that sum up to no more than *n* and where the highest exponent is *<= hi*. At every step, we can either choose the next highest exponent arbitrarily between *1* and *min(hi, n)* or stop choosing exponents. So we have the recurrence

```
f(0, hi) = 1  for all hi >= 0
f(n, hi) = 1 + sum(e = 1 to min(hi, n), f(n - e, e - 1))
```

Which leads to a simple dynamic program to solve the problem. The answer is `f(n,n) - 1`. We need to subtract one, because we also counted the possiblity to not choose any exponents, which results in the sum `0`. This is however not allowed by the problem statement.

Here are a few results:

```
f(1,1) - 1 = 1
f(2,2) - 1 = 2
f(3,3) - 1 = 4
f(4,4) - 1 = 6
f(5,5) - 1 = 9
f(6,6) - 1 = 13
f(7,7) - 1 = 18
f(8,8) - 1 = 24
f(9,9) - 1 = 32
f(10,10) - 1 = 42
f(11,11) - 1 = 54
f(12,12) - 1 = 69
f(13,13) - 1 = 87
f(14,14) - 1 = 109
```

Comment: Your logic is correct. However, can you explain your recurance relation?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: I changed it, because it was wrong. It should now be correct, and I added an explanation

Comment: +1 for the logic. However, I am somehow still not clear about your DP formulation.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: I have shown that we just need to count the number of different sequences `e[1] < ... <  e[m]` with `e[1] + ... + e[m] <= n`. The recurrence does exactly that. We pick the exponents from highest to lowest. `hi` is an upper bound for the next exponent to enforce the `<` relation. It can happen that `hi > n`, but obviously it makes no sense to choose an exponent > n because then we will never get the sum `<= n`

Comment: This is Sloane sequence http://oeis.org/A026906 which in turn is the sequence of partial sums of http://oeis.org/A000009 . See the latter page for a variety of computation possibilities. See http://oeis.org/A000009/b000009.txt for a list of A000009 up to N=1999, from which you can trivially compute the partial sums.

Comment: @rici: I found that as well, but I still think it's useful to see how to derive the recurrence (which can also be used to compute the results)

Answer (score 1):

If there are no parentheses involved, then:

Not a programming question, but a combinatorics one. The operands are fixed, and you are just selecting `N-1` operators to place between them from a pool of 2 (`+`, `*`). There are `2^(N-1)` ways of selecting operands.

```
N=2: 2^(2-1) = 2^1 = 2 (+, *)
N=3: 2^(3-1) = 2^2 = 4 (++, +*, *+, **)
```

No programming required, just maths.

EDIT: As Niklas B. points out, your own examples do not match the criteria you set out. The formula above is for "exactly N twos". If you're looking for "at most N twos", interpreted as "between 1 and N twos" (because I'm not sure what the result would be if you have 0 of them), then it's `2^N-1`:

```
N=2: 2^2-1 = 4-1 = 3 (+, *, none)
N=3: 2^3-1 = 8-2 = 7 (++, +*, *+, **, +, *, none)
```

FURTHER EDIT: If you're counting *values*, then you do need some programming. The easiest solution is to use a hash map with keys that are the values, and count frequencies as you brute-force through the combinations. Dynamic Programming in this case would be more trouble than it's worth, seeing as the complexity is O(N^2), and you probably aren't trying to calculate million-operand formulae, while the bit with operator precedence would make for a not very intuitive algorithm.

Comment: I don't know, this seems inconsistent with the examples. I think asking for clarification before writing an answer would be a good idea

Comment: @NiklasB.: How is it inconsistent? He also says "if n=2 than only 2..." and "for n=3, .... so total of 4", same as my results. EDIT: Oh, I missed "at least" and the things he doesn't count for the smaller `n`... I'll add that.

Comment: Yes, now the inconsistency with OPs expected results is apparent: 3 != 2 and 7 != 4. OP expressed himself very confusingly, unfortunately

Comment: @NiklasB.: Yes, I agree.

Comment: @NiklasB. I don't think `2^(n-1)` will be check out n=4, there will be [8,10,16] in n = 4, we know n = 3, there will be [2,4,6,8], so all for n=4 is [2,4,6,8,10,16] six distinct values.

Comment: @Tim: Yeah, I realized that. I had the wrong recurrence, but I have the correct one now in my answer